# Copy rows in different sheets - different rows VB Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am having three worksheets in a spreadsheet. I want to copy from particular row until last data row and paste them in second, third worksheets (second, third - different row number than first worksheet)

```
  Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Source As Worksheet
        Dim Target As Worksheet
        Dim Target1 As Worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FirstRow2Copy As Long
        Dim FirstRowCQuote As Long
        Dim FirstRowIQuote As Long
    Dim CQFCell As Excel.Range
        Dim IQFCell As Excel.Range

        Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheet1")
            Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheet1")
            Set Target1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheet2")


            With Source 'Worksheets("myWorksheet1") Last row
              LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row '.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
             End With       

        Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then        
            'Need to copy from this first row to last row
            FirstRow2Copy = FoundCell.Row + 1
        End If
Set CQuoteFCell = Target1.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not CQuoteFCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstRowCQuote = CQuoteFCell.Row + 1
    End If

    Set IQuoteFCell = Target1.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not IQuoteFCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstRowIQuote = IQuoteFCell.Row + 1
    End If

                'Need to copy rows from FirstRow2Copy untill LastRow - where paste them in Target sheet from RowNumber:FirstRowCQuote, 
                    'Paste the same rows in Target1 sheet from RowNumber:FirstRowIQuote
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim FoundCell As Range, LastCell As Range
With Worksheets("myWorksheet1")
    Set FoundCell = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    With .Range(FoundCell.Offset(1), LastCell).EntireRow
       .Copy Worksheets("mysheet1").Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1)
       .Copy Worksheets("mysheet2").Range("A:A").Find(what:="Enter the Quantity items:", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1)
   End With
End With
```

Comment: If I had specific from row for mysheet1,mysheet2 to paste, is that possible to done here? please refer my question

Comment: @Signa I made the modification, but please next time don't modify radically your question after answers have been posted. This makes the answers seem somehow aberrant.

Comment: Thank you ASH.. its working... and sorry for inconvenient